# getTime in chrome and firefox different result

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to convert `Date` object to `timestamp`,so create new `Date` object from datetime and use `getTime`,but it makes different result in Chrome and Firefox.it depends on timezone.

```
var date = new Date('2013-08-26T14:30:00');

date.getTime();
//1377527400000 in Chrome
//1377511200000 in Firefox

date.getTimezoneOffset();
//-270 in both of them
```

Firefox attention to timezone ,but chrome don't care about it.How can I force Firefox to act like chrome in this situation?And Why they act different?

I'm searching for the way difference than following psudo code:

```
if (Firefox){
    // plus with 270*60*1000
}
```

--
datetime returned from MySQL,then replace `space` by `T` in javascript.

Comment: Your timestamp string is not in a standardized format. Firefox and Chrome interpret those strings differently. The best thing to do would be to format your timestamp properly in the first place.

Comment: firefox can't understand `2013-08-26 14:30:00`

Comment: That's correct - the standard is RFC 2822, and that format does not meet that standard. It should be `26 Aug 2013 14:30:00`

Comment: @Pointy chrome return NaN by above format.

Comment: Sorry - I did it incorrectly at first. I have updated the comment - the month name and not month number is required.  The other thing you can do is parse your own date format and construct a Date with numeric parameters.

Comment: If you have a datetime in mysql, you can convert it to a unix timestamp there, and then pass that value to Date directly (after multiplying it with 1000, because JS uses milliseconds).

Comment: there are a lot's of record returned from selecting,near 100,000 .so I prefer to do it by JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTHM6/3/)

try using the standard date/time format:

```
var date = new Date("mm dd, yy hh:mm:ss");
```

See your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTHM6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this format:

`(new Date('2013-08-26T14:30:00.0Z')).getTime();`

and you'l get 1377527400000 for both